# ASP.NET MVC Routing two GUIDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an action taking two GUIDs:

```
public class MyActionController : Controller
{
  //...

  public ActionResult MoveToTab(Guid param1, Guid param2)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

I would like the following URI to map to the action:

```
/myaction/movetotab/1/2
```

...with 1 corresponding to param1 and 2 to param2.

What will the route look like, and is it possible to map the arguments to parameters with a type of Guid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to map your parameters to `System.Guid`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MoveToTab",
    "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}",
    new { controller = "MyAction", action = "MoveToTab",
        param1 = System.Guid.Empty, param2 = System.Guid.Empty }
);
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MoveToTab2",
    "myaction/movetotab/{param1}/{param2}",
    new { controller = "MyAction", action = "MoveToTab",
        param1 = System.Guid.Empty, param2 = System.Guid.Empty }
);
```

Comment: check your params...I think the second one should be param2 not param1.

Comment: Does this work because Guid takes a string as a parameter in one of its constructor overloads, or does the MVC framework cast the incoming string from the URL to a Guid? Will this process work for any object?

Comment: This things are handled by MVC framework (DefaultModelBinder)

Comment: Be careful using this. It'll work fine if your users are clicking on links, but if they ever type in something like `controller/action/abc123`, you'll get an exception saying that Guid cannot be null (naturally, since `abc123` can't be made into a valid Guid). A workaround would be to make the Guid nullable in the controller, but then you have the weirdness that an empty Guid means no Guid was provided and a null Guid is an invalid Guid.

Answer (score 3):

You can take in your two GUIDs as strings, and convert them to actual GUID objects using the GUID constructor that accepts a string value. Use the route that eu-ge-ne provided.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MoveToTab",
    "myaction/movetotab/{param1}/{param2}",
    new { controller = "MyAction", action = "MoveToTab", param1 = "", param2 = "" }
);

  public ActionResult MoveToTab(string param1, string param2)
  {
    Guid guid1 = new Guid(param1);
    Guid guid2 = new Guid(param2);
  }
```